# Post variable not passing

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, variables, post

Any idea why this doesn't work? I have tried to see if the button clicked actually works with alerts, had alerts as well as before and after the ajax code and they both worked.

```
var selectedCheckboxes = "12421";

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                $(".editArticle").on("click",function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "test.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: { selectedCheckboxes: "selectedCheckboxes" },
                        success: function(response){
                              //do action  
                        },
                        error: function(){
                              // do action
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
```

the link:

```
 <a href="test.php" class="editArticle">Edit</a>
```

test.php

```
<?php
echo $_POST["selectedCheckboxes"];
?>
```

Comment: if you echo "hello" in the ajax.. Do you even get there?

Comment: check that url is correct or not check in developer tools or firebug

Comment: I have created an alert in the success of ajax and it passes

Comment: Define "doesn't work."  What *does* it do?

Comment: First, you do realize you're sending the string `"selectedCheckboxes"` and not the value you intended? Second, you're calling the function on a link (`<a>`) click - you need to call preventDefault on the event, or change to a different HTML element (such as a button).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="editArticle">Edit</a>
```

If you want the output of the php in your page you have to do something like this in your javascsript

```
$(".editArticle").on("click",function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "test.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { selectedCheckboxes: selectedCheckboxes },
                    success: function(response){
                          $("body").html(response);
                    },
                    error: function(){
                          // do action
                    }
                });
            });
```

You may need to change the "body" tag.. or not
depends on what the teste.php returns

Well, if you don't want the output to be placed inside your current page html, maybe a different aproach would be better.
Maybe there are better answers but you could try something like:

```
<form method="post" action="test.php" onsubmit="javascript:$('#selectedCheckboxes').val(selectedCheckboxes);">
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="selectedCheckboxes" id="selectedCheckboxes">
    <input type="submit" value="Edit">
</form>
```

You would have to style the submit input 
Does the idea help? No ajax though.

Comment: Thing is the page also needs to switch to the other document. For example I have selected an article with a checkbox, I click on edit. The selected checkbox value must be posted in order to load in the right article from the database that will be put in for example test.php.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't that clear, I do need to be redirected to test.php at the same time that the variable is posted. I want to go on in test.php to work with the post variable not the current document.

Comment: You'll send the post and: $("body").html(response) outputs the test.php response to your html body. Sorry if i'm not understanding correctly. Isn't this what you need?

Comment: I wanted to be redirected to test.php to further process the variable. I don't want to work on the same file anymore after the click basically.

Comment: Still doesnt work, but thanks for helping me on the right way, should manage from here!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're not seeing the AJAX reqeust go through is because when the you click on the anchor tag, the browser is performing the default action of navigating to 'test.php', which cancels the AJAX call. Since you are simply GET'ing that page, and not POST'ing to it, there is nothing in `$_POST`. In order to prevent this default action, either use a `span` instead of an `a` tag (recommended), or prevent the default action, doing something like this:

```
<a href="#" class="editArticle">Edit</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you want to pass *selectedCheckboxes* as JSON to the Server. In this case you need to actually pass your *selectedCheckboxes* variable to the Server.
Like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: selectedCheckboxes,
    success: function(response){
        //do action  
    },
    error: function(){
        // do action
    }
});
```

The problem with your code is that you passed a new JSONObject containing a String that contains "selectedCheckboxes". You did not pass the actual variable.

Answer (score -1):

You try to pass a variable `selectedCheckboxes` but unfortunately with double ("") quotes you passing a string as **selectedCheckboxes**

Use below code

```
var selectedCheckboxes = "12421";

var dataObject = {};
data[selectedCheckboxes] = 1;
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                $(".editArticle").on("click",function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "test.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: dataObject ,
                        success: function(response){
                              //do action  
                        },
                        error: function(){
                              // do action
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score -1):

Put a return false; after ajax call

Comment: You can write a comment.

Comment: Adding some explanation to your answer will make it more useful to others, and make it more likely to be upvoted as useful.